# How to find the union and intersection of linked lists of strings?

Tags: c, string, data-structures, linked-list

I have tried to code the union and intersection of the 2 linked lists. However, I'm unsuccessful in creating the linked list of strings as its function fails to display and also insert nodes into the list. The code is only able to read the strings of linked list 1. I would want to know the approach to creating a linked list of strings.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct node{
    char* data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

NODE* create(char* data){
    NODE* newnode = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

void insertAtBeg(NODE **head, char* data){
    NODE *newnode = create(data);
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = (*head);
    (*head) = newnode;
}

void display(NODE *temp){
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d->",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int isPresent(NODE *head, char* data){
    NODE *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        if(temp->data == data)
            return 1;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

NODE* getUnion(NODE* head1, NODE* head2){
    NODE* result = NULL;
    NODE *t1 = head1;
    NODE *t2 = head2;

    while(t1 != NULL){
        insertAtBeg(&result, t1->data);
        t1 = t1->next;
    } 

    while(t2 != NULL){
        if(!isPresent(result,t2->data))
            insertAtBeg(&result, t2->data);
        t2 = t2->next;
    } 
    return result;
}

NODE* getIntersection(NODE *head1,NODE *head2){
    NODE* result = NULL;
    NODE *t1 = head1;
    
    while(t1 != NULL){
        if(isPresent(head2,t1->data))
            insertAtBeg(&result,t1->data);
        t1 = t1->next;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    NODE* head1 = NULL;
    NODE* head2 = NULL;
    NODE* intersection = NULL;
    NODE* unin = NULL;
    int m,n;
    char *arr;

    printf("Enter the size of the linked list1:\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter the elements:\n");
   
    for(int i = 0; i< m ; i++){
        scanf("%s",arr[i]);
        insertAtBeg(&head1,arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\nDisplaying linked list1:\n");
    display(head1);

    printf("\nEnter the size of linked list 2:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the elements:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i< n ; i++){
        scanf("%s",arr[i]);
        insertAtBeg(&head2,arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\nDisplaying linked list2:\n");
    display(head2);

    unin = getUnion(head1,head2);
    intersection = getIntersection(head1,head2);

    printf("\nUnion list:\n");
    display(unin);

    printf("\nIntersection list:\n");
    display(intersection);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘insertAtBeg’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   84 |         insertAtBeg(&head1,arr[i]);
      |                            ~~~^~~
      |                               |
      |                               char
q.c:16:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
   16 | void insertAtBeg(NODE **head, char* data){
      |                               ~~~~~~^~~~
q.c:94:31: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘insertAtBeg’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   94 |         insertAtBeg(&head2,arr[i]);
      |                            ~~~^~~
      |                               |
      |                               char
q.c:16:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
   16 | void insertAtBeg(NODE **head, char* data){
```

Comment: This function call insertAtBeg(&head1,arr[i]);  "expects to find" a function(NODE **p, char c); ,  the element type of the array at index i, arr[i]  (the example I gave is for type char c).

Comment: @MZM I used a similar approach before it didn't show much difference

Answer (score 1):

Several issues with the code so I made some changes, at minimum, to point out one issue and also placed printf statement to help in debugging (needs to b done as you're iteratively developing the code).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node{
    char* data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

NODE* create(char* data){
    NODE* newnode = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

void insertAtBeg(NODE **head, char* data){
printf("<in insertAtBeg(NODE **head, char* data) \n");
    NODE *newnode = create(data);
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = (*head);
    (*head) = newnode;
}

void display(NODE *temp){
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d->",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int isPresent(NODE *head, char* data){
    NODE *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        if(temp->data == data)
            return 1;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

NODE* getUnion(NODE* head1, NODE* head2){
    NODE* result = NULL;
    NODE *t1 = head1;
    NODE *t2 = head2;

    while(t1 != NULL){
        insertAtBeg(&result, t1->data);
        t1 = t1->next;
    } 

    while(t2 != NULL){
        if(!isPresent(result,t2->data))
            insertAtBeg(&result,t2->data);
        t2 = t2->next;
    } 
    return result;
}

NODE* getIntersection(NODE *head1,NODE *head2){
    NODE* result = NULL;
    NODE *t1 = head1;
    
    while(t1 != NULL){
        if(isPresent(head2,t1->data))
            insertAtBeg(&result, t1->data);
        t1 = t1->next;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    NODE* head1 = NULL;
    NODE* head2 = NULL;
    NODE* intersection = NULL;
    NODE* unin = NULL;
    int m,n;
    char *arr;
NODE* result = NULL;

insertAtBeg(&head2,&arr[0]);
insertAtBeg(&result, "c"); // t1->data); was data allocated memory?

/*
    printf("Enter the size of the linked list1:\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter the elements:\n");
   
    for(int i = 0; i< m ; i++){
        scanf("%s",arr[i]);
        insertAtBeg(&head1,arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\nDisplaying linked list1:\n");
    display(head1);

    printf("\nEnter the size of linked list 2:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the elements:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i< n ; i++){
        scanf("%s",arr[i]);
        insertAtBeg(&head2,arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\nDisplaying linked list2:\n");
    display(head2);

    unin = getUnion(head1,head2);
    intersection = getIntersection(head1,head2);

    printf("\nUnion list:\n");
    display(unin);

    printf("\nIntersection list:\n");
    display(intersection);
*/
    return 0;
}

Output:    
<in insertAtBeg(NODE **head, char* data) 
<in insertAtBeg(NODE **head, char* data)
```